# Asset file size overview after compiling an app?

Tags: ios, asset-pipeline, filesize

i´ve just created an iOS app that contains lots of media. 
Now i just want to know if it´s possible to get an overview of all single files as a report or something like that?

(e.g. Unity3d has this kind of feature. You can see all textures, shaders and so. Maybe Apple already included something...)

Thanks for tips on that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slender](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slender/id493656257?ls=1&mt=12)(App Store Link) might do what you are looking for.